# Appends only last value when looping through Json array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am looping through a json array and append some of its value to a a div. Looping through works fine. But when i have multiple value in the json. It appends only the last value.

Here is my json

```
{"msg":[{"id":22,"created_at":"2017-01-16 08:57:43","updated_at":"2017-01-16 08:57:43","profile_name":"VFX DESIGNER","experience":"0-2","skill":"s:10:\"MYSQL,JAVA\";","user_id":"2","comments":"sadsads","aptitude":"yes"},
{"id":23,"created_at":"2017-01-16 08:57:43","updated_at":"2017-01-16 08:57:43","profile_name":"MAYA ","experience":"0-2","skill":"s:10:\"MYSQL,JAVA\";","user_id":"2","comments":"sadsads","aptitude":"yes"}]}
```

When i loop through to get the profile name , it shows only MAYA in the 2nd value. and VFX DESIGNER is not appended.

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
        $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){
            $("#profiles_name ul").empty();
            $("#profiles_name ul").append("<a  href = javascript:getCandidates(this) data-value = "+titleObj.user_id+"/"+titleObj.id+"><li>"+titleObj.profile_name+"</li></a><li class = divider></li>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Take the `.empty()` outside of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `("#profiles_name ul").empty();` In every iteraion it removes everything in `("#profiles_name ul")` and then appends a new `a`.

Use the `empty()`  before the first `each`, it will clean your element and then iterate over the data.

```
$("#profiles_name ul").empty();

$.each(data,function(key,value){
   $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){
      $("#profiles_name ul").append("<a  href = javascript:getCandidates(this) data-value = "+titleObj.user_id+"/"+titleObj.id+"><li>"+titleObj.profile_name+"</li></a><li class = divider></li>");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#profiles_name ul").empty();
$.each(data,function(key,value){
        $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){

            $("#profiles_name ul").append("<a  href = javascript:getCandidates(this) data-value = "+titleObj.user_id+"/"+titleObj.id+"><li>"+titleObj.profile_name+"</li></a><li class = divider></li>");
        });
    });
```

Empty `profiles_name ul` before loop

Answer (score 0):

Create a string and then append it to get the desired output.

```
var str = "";
$.each(data,function(key,value){
    $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){
        str +="<a  href = javascript:getCandidates(this) data-value = "+titleObj.user_id+"/"+titleObj.id+"><li>"+titleObj.profile_name+"</li></a><li class = divider></li>";
    });
});

$("#profiles_name ul").empty();
$("#profiles_name ul").append(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes right because in each loop you making UL empty and then append newly created html...
so:
Just once empty UL once:

```
$("#profiles_name ul").empty();
```

Then loop through data and append html to it:

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
        $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){

            $("#profiles_name ul").append("<a  href = javascript:getCandidates(this) data-value = "+titleObj.user_id+"/"+titleObj.id+"><li>"+titleObj.profile_name+"</li></a><li class = divider></li>");
        });
    });
```

Hope this will help to you